# Spark data set count is taking much time

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am using count function to know whether count is greater than 0 or not.
But it is taking more than 5 mins to give the size of the particular column with of 40,00,000 items.

Below is my code junk.

```
specficManufacturerdetailsSource = source.filter(col("ManufacturerSource").equalTo(individualManufacturerName));
specficManufacturerdetailsTarget = target.filter(col("ManufacturerTarget").equalTo(individualManufacturerName));

manufacturerSourceCount=specficManufacturerdetailsSource.count();
manufacturerTargetCount=specficManufacturerdetailsTarget.count();


System.out.println("Size of specfic manufacturer source ML :"+manufacturerSourceCount+"Size of specfic manufacturer target"+manufacturerTargetCount);
if(manufacturerSourceCount > 0 && manufacturerTargetCount > 0 ){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on you above mentioned requirement you do not need count.

You can just use `findFirst()` in place of count and if you find any value by 
`manufacturerSourceCount.isPresent()` then it means `count > 0`